# Elementary convergence of power series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Prove that the power series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j$ converges at no
>   point on its circle of convergences $|z|=1$. Also, prove that the
>   power series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^j}{j^2}$ converges at every
>   point on its circle of convergences $|z|=1$.

This question is confusing to me. I know that a geometric series is divergent when $|z|>1$ and convergent when $|z|<1$, but what happens at the boundaries of the circle $|z|=1$? Also, the second part of the question is confusing too, I know that if I just use the comparison test that it will converge, but I don't think that is correct? What will happen if $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^j}{j^2}$, where $|z|>1$ or $|z|<1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first, since the $n$th term is $z^n$ and $|z^n| = |z|^n = 1$, we see that the terms do not converge to zero, hence the series cannot converge.

For the second, the $n$th term is $\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ and $|\frac{z^n}{n^2}| = \frac{1}{n^2}$ which is a convergent series, hence it converges absolutely for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$.

Since $\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \limsup_n e^{-\frac{2}{n} \ln n} = 1$, we see that the second series converges for $|z| <1$, and diverges for $|z|>1$.

Alternatively, you could use the ratio test: Since  $\rho =\lim_n |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_n |\frac{\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{z^{n}}{n^2}}| = |z|$, we see that the series converges for $|z| <1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: You beat me by 23 seconds. Yes, I will update the text...

Comment: Thanks Copper, this might be a stupid question but for a why does it have to converge to $0$ specifically? Is it because it is a circle centered at $0$?

Comment: No; let  $\sigma_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_n$. If $\sigma_n \to L$, then so does $\sigma_{n-1}$. Hence $\sigma_n - \sigma_{n-1} \to 0$. Hence $a_n \to 0$. It is a general 'feature' of convergent series.

Comment: Does that only apply to geometric series? Because it sometimes doesn't always converge to $0$, sometimes it converges to a specific number.

Comment: No, it is true of all convergent series. **All**. (We are talking about the individual terms of a series here.)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a lot!

Comment: Copper, I am curious to know one thing. When constructing the formula for geometric series $ a + ar + a r^2 + a r^3 + \cdots + a r^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k= a \, \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}, $, how did the person know to multiply by r for the second sum and then subtract the first series by the second getting $S-rS$? Is that from just playing around with it?

Comment: @Q.matin: Well, its a well know trick now, but I don't know when it was first 'discovered'. I imagine some playing around as you put it.

Answer (score 2):

For the first use that for $|z|=1$ $z^k$ doesn't converge to zero and hence the series can't be convergent,  for the second use comparism to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$.

When $|z|>1$ the sequence doesn't converge to zero and so the series can't be convergent, for $|z|<1$ the comparism gives us the absolut convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the second series is absolutely convergent for $|z|=1$ since $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.

For the first series: it diverges because $z^n=e^{in\theta},$ don't converge to $0$ for all $\theta$.